# Someone know a Windows application for MySQL that maintain a live connection all time?

Tags: mysql

I have a server that all time close the connection each 5 minutes and when I try to execute a command again it spend too much time for reconnect.

I has been test this:

Workbench.
Navicat
Toast
Heidi

Comment: If the server closes the connection after 5 minutes *no* application,by which I assume you mean a client, can keep it open longer. A new connection every five minutes does not use 'too much time', and if it does you can always increase the idle timeout at the server to say 10 minutes.

Comment: Thanks @EJP  This is a good idea, I will contact my hosting provider for ask about it.